# Angularjs showing/hiding html element with modal open

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

so I want to have a loading spinner icon appear on my page when a user clicks on a button that opens a modal, and have the spinner disappear when the modal is open and the document inside the modal has loaded. Right now, I've got the spinner to pop up at the right time but it will stay for 5 or 6 seconds after the modal is open.

Here is my javascript:

```
vm.build = {
            rowType : {
                type : 'click',
                action : function(item) {
                    vm.showBigSpinner = true;
                    if (vm.flag == false) {
                        vm.flag = true;
                        var saveFileName = item.backupDocumentId;
                            backupDetailApi.backupDocumentg.get({
                                filename : saveFileName
                            }).$promise
                            .then(function(result) {
                                vm.backupDocument = utilService.syntaxHighlight(angular.fromJson(result.content,'undefined', false, true));
                                var template = '<div class="modal-header">'
                                    + '<h2 class="col-lg-12">Backup Document</h2>'
                                    + '</div>'
                                    + '<div id="document" class="modal-body form-horizontal">'
                                    + '<div style="margin: 0px 20px">'
                                    + '<pre>'
                                    + vm.backupDocument
                                    + '</pre>'
                                    + '</div>'
                                    + '</div>'
                                    + '<div class="modal-footer fixed-modal-footer">'
                                    + '<button id="markup-copy" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" ng-click="main.clipboard()" bs-tooltip="\'Copy to clipboard\'"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-clipboard"></i></button>'
                                    + '<button class="btn" ng-click="main.cancel()">Close</button>'
                                    + '</div>';
                                vm.flag = false;
                                vm.showBigSpinner = false;
                                $uibModal
                                .open({

                                    animation : true,
                                    windowClass : 'app-modal-window modal',
                                    template : template,
                                    resolve : {
                                        backupDocument : function() {
                                            return angular.toJson(angular.fromJson(result.content,'undefined',false,true),true);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    controller : function backupDocumentModalController($uibModalInstance, backupDocument) {

                                        var vm = this;
                                        function cancel() {
                                            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                                        }
                                        vm.cancel = cancel;
                                        vm.flag = false;
                                        vm.showBigSpinner = false;
                                    },
                                    controllerAs : 'main'
                                });
                            })
                        // vm.flag = false;
                    }
                }
            }}
```

and the html...

```
<i ng-show="main.showBigSpinner" class="fa fa-5x fa-spinner fa-spin" style="position: absolute; left: 48.5%; margin-top: 10%"></i>
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to how I can get this spinner to go away when I want it to? I was thinking maybe a promise.

Edit: 
The spinner is outside of the modal and appears before the modal pops up. I want it to lgo away after the data in the modal has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

When your modal show up, his controller is overriding your `vm` variable, that was your previous controller (I believe).

You can use two ways to solve this problem:

### 1: Move the spinner logic up to the rootScope

or, much better

### 2: pass a reference of the first controller to your modal controller

To do this, you can modify your `$uibModal.open` argument as follow:

```
$uibModal.open({
  animation : true,
  windowClass : 'app-modal-window modal',
  template : template,
  resolve : function() {
    return {
      backupDocument: angular.toJson(angular.fromJson(result.content,'undefined',false,true),
      ctrl: vm
    };
  },
  controller : function backupDocumentModalController($uibModalInstance, data) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.backupDocument = data.backupDocument;
    var parentCtrl = data.ctrl;
    function cancel() {
      $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }
    parentCtrl.showBigSpinner = false;
  },
  controllerAs : 'main'
});
```

I probably made a few typos but I hope you got the concept.

Comment: this is good, I will try passing a reference and see if that helps!

Comment: By the way, I don't remember if the modalInstance is auto-injected in the controller by ui-bootstrap, since I haven't use it recently. If it's undefined, or if it contains your data and data is undefined, you can wrap also the modal instance in the parent controller to access it by ```parentCtrl.instance```

Answer (score 0):

But do you have your spinner in modal? It looks like this, cause for modal you use `main` for controller and in your HTML you have `main.showBigSpinner`. If it is outside modal (in your main view), rename `var vm = this` inside modal controller to, for example, `var viewModel = this` (and all its occurrences in modal controller). Then, by using `vm`, you access "parent" controller in line `vm.showBigSpinner = false;`, not modal controller.

Comment: good question, the spinner is outside of the modal. So you're saying if I rename my `var vm = this` to something unique, I can access it from outside the controller?

Comment: @anthonystoico Something like this, by not exactly - `var vm = this` from modal controller overloads `var vm = this` from main controller, and you think you access main controller - but you access modal controller. If you rename `vm` inside modal controller to `viewModel` (but only inside modal controller) you will be able to access main controller by `vm` variable. My point is IMO similar to Luca Argenziano's answer.

Comment: I like this idea but I am scared to change my modal controller because it is generic and used very often across my app.

Comment: wait, ignore my last comment, this particular modal is not generic!

Comment: @anthonystoico Ok, but I am talking about changes in `backupDocumentModalController` function - name change is encapsulated here and does not affect anything outside.